# Regex issue python capturing group that can exist but does not always exist

Tags: python, regex

I was trying now for 1h to figure it out on regex101... but I did not solve it. Here are small list who is going thru my regex:

```
list = ["This.is.Test.Nr.One.C01B01.42U.Rack.08-Datacenter1",
        "Is.this.Nr.Two.C03B03.London.48U.Rack.04-Datacenter4",
        "This.Number.Random.C02.Frankfurt.42U.Rack.12-Datacenter1",
        "This.is.Random.Number.C08B01.Zuerich.Rack.01-Datacenter2"
```

Now I want to capture 5 groups. I tried following regex: `\A(.+)\.(C\d{1,2})(B\d{1,2})?.?(42U|48U)?.+-(.+)`

Group1:

```
This.is.Test.Nr.One
Is.this.Nr.Two
This.Number.Random
This.is.Random.Number
```

Group2:

```
C01
C03
C02
C08
```

Group3:

```
B01
B03
**missing but should still work for all the other groups**
B01
```

Group4:

```
42U
48U
42U
**missing but should still work for all the other groups**
```

Group5:

```
Datacenter1
Datacenter4
Datacenter1
Datacenter2
```

**EDIT:** I fogot there can be also a case where it is like this:

`Is.this.Nr.Two.B03.London.48U.Rack.04-Datacenter4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make the match to the C, B and U parts optional and use the capturing groups inside

```
^(?:(.+?)\.(C\d{1,2}))?(?:.*?(B\d{1,2}))?\.(?:.*?(42U|48U))?.*-(.+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqghp8/1)

Comment: Wow... I have even troubles reading that. But I think I will understand it with the Regex101 explanation on the side. Little issue doh. It does not match the last one... at least group01 does not match it...

Comment: As far as I can tell this is the fix `^(.+)\.(?:(C\d{1,2}))?(?:.*?(B\d{1,2}))?\.(?:.*?(42U|48U))?.*-(.+)$` but please correct me if I am wrong... No regex pro at all...

Comment: @YvesNr1 Ah, the pattern I posted was would be valid for the values before the last update to your question. Your suggestion would get your matches indeed.

Comment: You could make the pattern a bit more performant `^([^.]+(?:\.(?![BC]\d{2})[^.]+)*)\.(?:(C\d{2})(?:\.(?![BC]\d{2})[^.\n]+)*?)?(?:(B\d{2})(?:\.(?![BC]\d{2})[^.\n]+)*?)?(?:.*?\.(42U|48U))?.*-(.+)` See https://regex101.com/r/2fmleE/1/

Answer (score 0):

The last one was a mindbender, but this is what that works.

```
^([a-zA-Z.]*\.)(C\d{1,2})?(B\d{1,2})?([.A-Za-z]*)(42U|48U)?.+-(.+)
```

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/4w7NeP/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
(.+)\.(C\d{1,2})?(B\d{1,2})?(?:\.[A-Za-z]+)*\.(42U|48U)?.+-(.+)
```

will work.
Testing code is following:

```py
import re

list_ = [
    "This.is.Test.Nr.One.C01B01.42U.Rack.08-Datacenter1",
    "Is.this.Nr.Two.C03B03.London.48U.Rack.04-Datacenter4",
    "This.Number.Random.C02.Frankfurt.42U.Rack.12-Datacenter1",
    "This.is.Random.Number.C08B01.Zuerich.Rack.01-Datacenter2",
    "Is.this.Nr.Two.B03.London.48U.Rack.04-Datacenter4",
]


pattern = re.compile(
    r'(.+)\.'  # group1 and trailing literal "."
    r'(C\d{1,2})?'  # group2(optional)
    r'(B\d{1,2})?'  # group3(optional)
    r'(?:\.[A-Za-z]+)*\.'   # skipping for example multiple ".London" and "."
    r'(42U|48U)?.+-'  # group4(optional) and ... -
    r'(.+)'  # group5
)
for text in list_:
    match_object = pattern.search(text)
    if match_object:
        print(match_object.groups())
    else:
        print('Not matched')
```

output:

```py
('This.is.Test.Nr.One', 'C01', 'B01', '42U', 'Datacenter1')
('Is.this.Nr.Two', 'C03', 'B03', '48U', 'Datacenter4')
('This.Number.Random', 'C02', None, '42U', 'Datacenter1')
('This.is.Random.Number', 'C08', 'B01', None, 'Datacenter2')
('Is.this.Nr.Two', None, 'B03', '48U', 'Datacenter4')
```